# How to get response message from AJAX data

Tags: java, ajax, jquery, servlets

Here  I  write the response to ajax response object

```
protected void writeAjaxResponse(HttpServletRequest req 
                                 ,HttpServletResponse resp,String result){
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = resp.getWriter();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.println(result);
        return;

    }
```

And later I called

```
writeAjaxResponse(req, resp, "<p style=color:red>Error occured recording
                                                           your feedback!</p>");
```

In jquery

```
$.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'savefeedback',
                  data: 'feedbacker='+feedbacker+'feedbackeremail=
                   '+feedbackeremail+'feedbacker='+feedbackermsg,
                  success:function(data){
                   alert(data); //here is the pin point


                    }
                });
```

But in alert I am getting

```
    [object XMLDocument]
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my servlet `doPost()` method

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException { 

         String feedbacker = req.getParameter("feedbacker");
         String  feedbackeremail = req.getParameter("feedbackeremail");
         String  feedbackermsg = req.getParameter("feedbackermsg");

        boolean saveFeedback = MailSenderServlet.
            saveFeedback(req, resp, feedbackeremail, "",
                  feedbackermsg, feedbacker, feedbackeremail);
        if(saveFeedback){
            writeAjaxResponse(req, resp, "Feedback received succesfully!");
        }else{
            writeAjaxResponse(req, resp, "Error occured  !");
        }

    }
```

But i am expecting my response message.

Please let me know if I missed something.

Please help!!!!

Comment: If you are using Chrome, you could use `console.log(data)` and check the console to find out how your response object exactly looks like.

Comment: dataType:'html' //or json or anything? in ajax!

Comment: I saw empty console in firebug and chrome :(

Comment: `dataType: JSON ,` in $.ajax!!!

Comment: @NoobUnChained yeah,thanks.let me check that.

Comment: @NoobUnChained Nope..Nothing happend.Same result.

Comment: @Baadshah you need to use `console.log(data)` instead of `alert(data)` to see something in the console.

Comment: @w4rumy ok.lemme try that and i'l get back to you.

Comment: Did you see what exactly is `result` in the server side ? And can you show us your `doPost()` ?

Comment: There should be two `ifs` , I guess in that `doPost()` !!!

Comment: Thankyou all for the prompt support.Now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 30 min reserach

I found the `MIME type` missing and changed my method to

```
protected void writeAjaxResponse(HttpServletRequest req 
                                 ,HttpServletResponse resp,String result){
       resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = resp.getWriter();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.println(result);
        return;

    }
```

Thanks to @Noob  @ w4rumy @user2207792 for the prompt support.